# How to call a custom directive on click in angular js for file upload?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload, angularjs-directive

I have seen a lot of solutions here in SO to upload file in Angular JS. Most of them install additional modules(like ngUpload,angular-file-upload) or creating a custom directive  which is invoked as soon as the upload is done.

The custom directive way is working and i am upload to get a hook to the files uploaded. But i want the upload to start only after a button is clicked. So i tried to call the directive on click, but not able to read the file input in the directive.

Custom Directive I am using:

```
app.directive('fdInput', [function () {
return {
    template: '<div></div>',
    replace: true,
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.on('change', function  (evt) {
            var files = evt.target.files;
            console.log(files[0].name);
            console.log(files[0].size);
            scope.callbackFn({file :  sfiles[0]});
        });
   }
};
}]);
```

Custom directive code on click:

```
app.directive('fdInput', [function () {
return {
    template: '<div></div>',
    replace: true,
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
         scope.processFile= function() {
             console.log('inside processFile method');
         };
   }
};
}]);
```

Is there a way that i can read the file in the second code like i did in the first one?

I want to achieve file upload on click in Angular with out including additional modules. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve this by accessing the controller scope in your directive.

This [link](http://www.undefinednull.com/2014/02/11/mastering-the-scope-of-a-directive-in-angularjs/) here on directive scope gives some very good examples to get started.

Hope that helps!

Comment: This concept worked for me but using this link https://uncorkedstudios.com/blog/multipartformdata-file-upload-with-angularjs

But I am now facing issue while sending the form data to the REST API.  Any link as to how to send the file content?